# Queues and List to accessing elements

Tags: python, multithreading, wxpython

I have a GUI application that uses a separate thread to read some data, create a list and load it into a combobox.

Example:

```
class MyDialog(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, title):

        lock = threading.Lock()
        self.list_of_emails = []
        self.start_read_thread()

    def read_employees(self, read_file):
        list_of_emails = []

        with lock:
            with open(read_file) as f_obj:
               #code to read and split the data and create an employee object left out
               list_of_emails = [employee.email for employee in employees]


        wx.CallAfter(self.emp_selection.Append, list_of_emails)

    def start_read_thread(self):
        filename = 'employee.json'
        with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1) as executor:
            executor.submit(self.read_employees, filename)


app = wx.App(False)
frame = MyDialog(None, "Crystal Rose")
app.MainLoop()
```

My problem is I also have to access that same list, the `self.list_of_emails = []` from the main thread. When the user selects an employee from the combobox I'm going to pull the corresponding employee object based on index. By the time I'm ready to access the `self.list_of_emails = []`, the thread that uses it, should be completed.

**Questions:**

1. However, suppose the `self.start_read_thread()` isn't completed, in the main thread do I need check if the thread is still alive and if so, use a lock object before using the list?
2. I'm aware of Queue, problem is, I'm unaware of how to access a specific element by index, the only work around I know is to create a temporary `list`. However, to me anyway this seems kind of inefficient. Is there anyway to treat a `Queue` like a `list` without explicitly creating a `list` and access an element by index?

Comment: A temporary list is fast and simple. You can't index into a `queue.Queue`, or access its members in any way, apart from the item currently at its head. There's another queue in the standard library, `collections.deque` which _is_ indexable, but it's not designed to be thread-safe. BTW, the usual way to be sure that a thread has finished is to call its `.join()` method.

Comment: If I were to use locks and list, would that be okay as well? or the temporary list is more efficient?

Comment: You can use a Lock if you like. Another option is to use an Event. The important thing is to not mess with an object that another thread may currently be modifying. We have various synchronization tools to make sure that doesn't happen, and there are usually multiple valid solutions. So play around with the options until you find something that does the job and that you can understand. ;) A common pattern is to have one thread that reads data and puts it into a Queue, and another thread grabs stuff from the queue as it becomes available.

Comment: I think I'm going to use the `Queue` and temporary list solution. By the time the user is selecting items from the combobox, it should have already of loaded, if not I can check if it's alive and and to wait.

Comment: Sounds good to me.